# Matrix Derivative of $X^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

For a nxn matrix $X$, I want to take the derivative of the function $F(X) = X^3$.

What would the derivative operator look like? I would imagine it's just the Jacobian...? Is the solution just $3X^2$?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Please review [this guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on how to ask a good question and edit your post accordingly. As it stands now it will attract downvotes. Having done a quick back of the envelope calculation the derivative appears to be some thing like $2X^2\otimes I + X\otimes X$

Comment: Certainly an optimist would hope that the derivative is, in some sense, $3X^2$, but there are some complications, as in @TedShifrin's good answer.

Comment: @mweiss I noticed that when I first saw the OP. I will take the liberty of editing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since matrix multiplication is not commutative, you have to be more careful and more explicit. Compute the derivative in the direction of a tangent vector (i.e., matrix) $H$:

\begin{align*}
Df_A(H) &= \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(A+tH)-f(A)}t \\
&= \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(A+tH)^3-A^3}t = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{(A+tH)(A+tH)(A+tH)-A^3}t \\
&= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{t(HA^2+AHA+A^2H) + t^2(AH^2+HAH+H^2A) + t^3H^3}t \\
&= \lim_{t\to 0} (HA^2+AHA+A^2H) + t(AH^2+HAH+H^2A) + t^2H^3 \\
&= HA^2+AHA+A^2H.
\end{align*}
Note that this is indeed linear in $H$, but is not of the form of matrix times $H$.  (If $A$ and $H$ happen to commute, as when $n=1$, then you get the naive guess $3A^2H$.)